# Determine type of the object which contains array Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object like below in Angular:

```
modifyList : {
    addItem : ImportItem[],
    removeItem : ImportItem[]
}

// ImportItem.ts:
export enum ImportItem {
   Item1='Item1',
   Item2='Item2'
   // ....
}
```

as of now I am using `any` type for `modifyList` object everywhere in the application, but I need to use specific type instead of `any`...

If I try to use 'object' type, then it does not allow me to access `.addItem` and `.removeItem` properties...

```
modifyList : any
modifyList.addItem //works fine

modifyList : object
modifyList.addItem //not able to access it, gives compilation error
```

What type can I provide to my object and can still access the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export interface ModifyListType { 
  addItem: ImportItem[]; 
  removeItem: ImportItem[]; 
}

// ImportItem.ts:
export enum ImportItem {
   Item1='Item1',
   Item2='Item2'
}
```

and use

```
modifyList : ModifyListType=new ModifyListType();
modifyList.addItem //Which will works fine
```

Comment: This works, but some of the unit tests are breaking due to this... Do I need to create mock of this in unit tests?

Comment: Yes Please @Learner1

Answer (score 1):

Make an interface called "ModifiedList":

```
export interface ModifiedList { 
  addItem: ImportItem[]; 
  removeItem: ImportItem[]; 
}
```

Comment: This works, but some of the unit tests are breaking due to this... Do I need to create mock of this in unit tests?